# Sonar issue - Remove this useless assignment to local variable

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using below mentioned piece of code:

```
IList<Comment> listComments = new List<Comment>();
foreach (var comment in paxComments.Where(x => x.Id== paxID))
{
    listComments.Add(new Comment()
    {
        CommentID = comment.CommentId,
        Text = comment.Comment,
    });
}
```

Here sonar is saying "Remove this useless assignment to local variable". How can I add to the list without initializing it with new keyword?

Sonar comment is **"Remove this useless assignment to local variable "listComments". "**

I went through below links but not getting my answer.

[Sonar complaining about useless assignment of local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342828/sonar-complaining-about-useless-assignment-of-local-variable)

[remove this useless assignment to local variable c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903201/remove-this-useless-assignment-to-local-variable-c-sharp)

Comment: Sonar comment is "Remove this useless assignment to local variable "listComments". "

Comment: What version of Sonar C# is installed on your SonarQube? Also, if you could post here the complete method body, it would be of great help identifying the problem.

Comment: Im not into Sonar, but the message is "Remove this useless assignment *to* local variable listComments". Maybe it does not pretend to say the variable is not needed but that the foreach could be done in a better way.

Comment: @Valeri: Below is the complete method:   private IList<Comment> GetPaxComments(IEnumerable<PaxComment> paxCmments, int paxID)
        {  IList<Comment> listComments = new List<Comment>();
foreach (var comment in paxComments.Where(x => x.Id== paxID))
{
    listComments.Add(new Comment()
    {
        CommentID = comment.CommentId,
        Text = comment.Comment,
    });
} return listComments }

Comment: @AshwiniKumar thanks for the method text. What version of Sonar C# are you using? I cannot reproduce the problem with the latest version and your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
IList<Comment> listComments = paxComments.Where(x => x.Id== paxID).ToList();
```

If these are of same type. Otherwise project the required fields after where:

```
IList<Comment> listComments = paxComments.Where(x => x.Id== paxID).Select(x=> new Comment({CommentId = x.commentId, Text = x.Text})).ToList();
```

I guess that ForEach loop is unnecessary.

Comment: I will have to commit the code to see if sonar issue goes off. But why listComments variable is useless in mentioned piece of code?

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not use any Code Review Tool. :D ---- There is no real reason for your logic being incorrect. Just that less lines of code could have achieved the same... (assuming my approach fixes your situation). Remember these are just "Presumed Good Rules" to follow - does not make any real difference. On lighter note I have seen some teams follow a practice that not more than 70 characters in a source code line, reasoning given was that you dont have to scroll horizontally during debug.

Comment: @AshwiniKumar you could install [SonarLint for Visual Studio](https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html), this way you will see the same issues as on your SonarQube before committing...

Comment: @Valeri SonarLint is installed. But it is not showing any error. But When I commit the code SonarQube gives error.

Comment: The `Select` implicitly loops the `IEnumerable` so I wonder what is complaining about. Simpler code? Faster code?

Comment: @bradbury9 in this case it should not complain. It complains with this message when you overwrite a value without using it. For example: `var a = 5; a = 10;`